# How can I search inside javascript text with firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

The "search" (magnifying glass) on the top-right hand corner of firebug does not search inside javascript blocks, so if I have, for example, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var fooBar = "baz"

</script>
```

somewhere in a page, I can't find where "fooBar" is located. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you switch to the script tab, it will search inside script tags. Just make sure the HTML file is selected in the file drop-down (it should be by default).

If you don't need to use Firebug specifically, you can also search in the View Source window.

Comment: Great! The view source does not work for me, because the page is totally AJAXy, but the search on the Script tab works.

Comment: Food for thought: Firebug 3 (currently in alpha) overlays Firefox's built-in dev tools. As such, it has Firefox's Debugger tab instead of a Script tab. The search box there is confusing to use, as it has special syntax for different kinds of searches that is only visible when the search box has focus before any text has been entered into it.

Prepending '!' will search for results in all files and '#' will search within the current file.

Answer (score -1):

FIREBUG does not search properly, it shows no result found... but IE Developer tools works best, as its gets highlighted even in framesets...